# How can share project (with github) while keeping private information in code?

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

For example, I'm creating a mobile app. To save me some time I have a small code that compile only in debug to bypass the login process with hardcoded credentials.

I now want to share the project on github, but I would want to keep that small code that save me a lot of time in debug :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using hard-coded variables in code, use environment variables.

```cs
#if DEBUG
    var username = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MySecretUsername");
    var password = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MySecretPassword");
    // auto-login
#endif
```

Then just put the variables in your environment on any machine that is needed. You could use a .BAT or powershell file to set the variables, but don't check this file into source control.

A word of caution: **Git stores everything in history. So even if you modified your files and committed the changes to git, *then* pushed to github, anyone could see the state of the file in the past and see the old credentials there.**

So I'd recommend changing the credentials on the server to something else in case someone looked at the file history.

Comment: Thanks. That make sense for a Windows app. In my case, this is a mobile app, and I spend a lot of time debugging on the phone. I don't think I can use that on a phone right?

Answer (score 1):

Building from Paul's answer...

Create a `credential.xyz` file (or similar) and check for that in your code. If it exists (or exists and is not zero-length, etc), use the credentials in the file.  If not, present your login screen.  Do not check this file in, but make it part of your build. If using Git, add `xyz` files to .gitignore for extra safety. You will need to do a little work to make it so builds work as expected for new users since they won't have this file.  Even a pre-build step to create the file if it does not exist might suffice.

You still have the issue of your history with hard-coded credentials in your history. If these credentials are used *anywhere else* (aka, you did not use a unique password specific for this app, the password is too similar to others you have used, etc.), you might want to consider options to start fresh with a new git history before sharing.  There might be other ways to do this, but that might be better as a new question. I would error on the side of 100% caution. You could always keep the old one around as a copy with that history.

Comment: I'll try that. don't worry about git, I didn't commit anything before sorting that out!

Comment: I can't find a way to add the .xyz file only in debug. Any idea?

Comment: Probably add it to all builds, but like you outlined, DEBUG only code to consume it.

Comment: That is what I did so far and its working. However, the release package now include a file with sensitive credentials. And I can't find a way to remove the file from release build

Comment: Use a post-build task to delete it from Release, or replace it with a benign copy? At this point what you are doing is a bit of "black magic" (did not want to use the word hack).

Comment: I tried, and despite the fact that the file is empty in my bin folder, the file in the app package is still there. I don't really understand the package process I guess....

Comment: Ahh. Create a cred.real.xyz cred.empty.xyz, pre-build, copy the corresponding xyz file to cred.xyz so the one you want is in the package and build.

Comment: Yes, I guess that is a solution.